# Update meta title and description for multiple stores

Tags: magento-1.9.3.4, meta-title, meta-description

I have 2 stores. In each store, the products have different metadata titles and descriptions. Now I want to erase the product metadata title and description from store 2 and check "use default value". So that store 2 is using the metadata from store 1.
The problem is , I have 3780 products... so manually isnt an option.
Who can help me?
regards

Answer (score 0):

***You can try below code......***

```
<?php
$storeId = "your storeId";
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productCollection->addStoreFilter($storeId);

foreach ($productCollection as $_productCollection) {
    $productObject = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($_productCollection->getId());
    $productObject->setMetaTitle('');
    $productObject->setMetaKeyword('');
    $productObject->setMetaDescription('');
    $productObject->save();
}
```